# Google Apps Sync Update Causes Weird Behavior

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email, outlook, google-apps-sync

We use Gmail as a paid service for our company email.  We converted to this over a year ago and things have been running smoothly.  Most of us use Google Apps Sync and this works well.  However, recently, we all received an email from Google saying that Google Apps Sync was successfully updated.  From then on, we all have been seeing weird behavior:

Firstly, several of my Outlook 2007 rules have been throwing errors, saying they couldn't be run and Outlook would remove the check mark from my rule (as if to turn it off).

Secondly, a handful of emails that used to be routed fine, are now being sent from an email address on behalf of another, thereby skipping existing Outlook rules.  This is the concerning part.

For example, one of our employees who quit several months ago had a Gmail account with us that has since been deactivated.  We made an alias so that any email his address might receive will be forwarded to us (we have this set up for four former employees using the groups functionality in Google mail).

Yet, I am getting email from this email address on behalf of the email address that is supposed to be sending the email.  This same scenario (although with different email addresses) is happening in many cases to several of us using Google mail and Google Apps Sync.

Anyone else see this or know how to fix this?

NOTE 1 - So I did some research on this and it seems this behavior is related to lists, in that when we set these "groups" a list is formed.  Not sure how it is connected...

Comment: Google Apps Sync seems to have been updated a few times since this was posted. Is this still an issue?

Comment: No longer an issue... I hate to close as to ding my rep, but if there's no activity...

Comment: Closing this question won't affect your reputation. Even if it's deleted it shouldn't affect your reputation because it's so old.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue that has been resolved in an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Google Apps Sync and this problem disappeared. I should also mention. I moved to Linux full-time, and now am using Thunderbird, which has its own host of issues with GAS... So that's another story.